# Access to iframe Object.prototype in IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an Iframe element on page and i need to create some prototype methods to Object inside iframe.

I got iframe window

```
var win = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
```

And then a tried to create methods. In FF, Chrome and IE9+ it's simple:

```
win.Object.prototype.func = myFunc;
```

But it doesn't work in IE8. I got undefined in win.Object.
At the same time **win.Element** works perfectly.

How can i get iframe Object in IE8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was pretty easy.
Was enough to create empty script in iframe - and objects (like a win.Object, win.Element etc) become available in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a `script` element in the `iframe` which creates a global variable in the outer window which points to the inner `Object`:

```js
var doc = iframe.contentDocument,
    s = doc.createElement('script');
s.text = "parent.Object2 = Object;";
doc.appendChild(s);
doc.removeChild(s);
```

Then, you can use `Object2.prototype`.